# How do I make my DIV ontop of a flash object inside an iFrame I don't control?

Tags: flash, iframe, html, layer, z-index

Basically, I have a DIV, which I've set to z-index: 100. I have an iframe which I set to z-index: 0. My 100 div is ontop of the frame on a normal webpage, but I have to load a flash page in the frame. Unfortunately the flash in the frame shows overtop of my 100 DIV. I can't set the z-index of the flash object because I don't control that webpage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you won't be able to do this. Flash objects have a tendency to jump in front of other content, regardless of z-index.

If all you're trying to do is hide the content of the ifram, a better solution would be to make it visibility:hidden or display:none or something similar.

Hope that helps.